# How to get WooCommerce product object in a custom shortcode to avoid errors

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, methods, shortcode

I have a function in which i am trying to get the product short description of the current product using the product id but i keep getting Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_short_description() on bool in

I have the following shortcode function where I am trying to get the product short description of the current WooCommerce product using the product id:

```
function custom_product_description( $atts ) {
    global $product;

    // Shortcode attribute (or argument)
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id'    => ''
    ), $atts, 'custom_product_description' );

    // If the "id" argument is not defined, we try to get the post Id
    if ( ! ( ! empty($atts['id']) && $atts['id'] > 0 ) ) {
       $atts['id'] = get_the_id();
    }

    // We check that the "id" argument is a product id
    if ( get_post_type($atts['id']) === 'product' ) {
        $product = wc_get_product($atts['id']);
    }

    $product_short_description = $product->get_short_description();

    return  $product_short_description;
}
```

but I keep getting the following error: 
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_short_description() on bool in …

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid this error for your custom shortcode, use the following instead:

```
function custom_product_description($atts){
    // Extract shortcode attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => get_the_ID(),
    ), $atts, 'product_description' ) );
    
    global $product;

    // If the product object is not defined, we get it from the product ID
    if ( ! is_a($product, 'WC_Product') && get_post_type($id) === 'product' ) {
        $product = wc_get_product($id);
    }
    
    if ( is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
        return $product->get_short_description();
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'product_description', 'custom_product_description');
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work now.

**USAGE:**

- Without a defined `id` argument on single product pages: `[product_description]`
- With a defined valid product ID as argument: `[product_description id="37"]`